# Can someone tell me why these two codes give different answers

Tags: matlab, size, reshape

First code:

```
kk8 = (kk1(:,:) .* (reshape((kk2(c,:,:)),12,6) ));
kk8(isnan(kk8))=0;
```

where `size(kk8)` returns

```
ans =

    12     6
```

Second code:

```
size( kk8(isnan((kk1(:,:) .* (reshape((kk2(c,:,:)),12,6) ))))=0 );
```

I'm doing some cheating here to see what happens – I thought it would be the same, but now `size(kk8)` returns

```
ans =

    1     60
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something like the following (in terms of size of arrays) in your first example:

```
kk8=kk1;
kk8(isnan(kk1))=0;
```

And in your second example you are doing something like

```
kk8(isnan(kk1))=0;
```

I assume that kk8 was not previously defined.

In your first example you create the array `kk8`, the same size as `kk1`, then modify some elements. In your second example you create `kk8` as a vector zeros corresponding to the number of `NaN`'s in `kk1`. That's why they will have different sizes, because they are created differently.

Comment: how should i do it to put it in just one line?

Comment: @user2604811 Leave it as two lines! I'm not sure how you would do this in a single line, and there is no real reason to.